# How to open a PIC graphic file with Delphi

Tags: delphi, graphics, image

I have images saved into a old database and I trying to convert them to BMP. Some of them have a header 01 00 00 01 and I cannot open because in accordance with the information given in [File signatures](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) this images are [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PICtor_PIC_image_format) files . Anybody knows how to open a PIC image with delphi. TBitmap, TPNGObject, TMetafile, TIcon and TJPEGImage doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike Lischke's [GraphicEx](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/libs/graphicex-library) Library can open .PIC files.

I'm sure there are other libraries around that can open .PIC files, but that's the first one I found.

Answer (score 0):

I would first verify that they are valid images. Try dumping to file with .pic extension and open with Irfanview.